# Load an image in certain cells using autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, swift2, uitableview

So Ive got a Feed displaying posts made by users (Using Parse). At present the cell contains a title, profile image of user who posted, the date, content(text), an imageView (for an image they post) and a like & comment button.

My question is, Using autolayout what is the best approach to displaying the image they posted. Currently I have the imageView height set to 0 at all times, I then reference the constant height of the imageView in the code. 
The app pulls down all the posts and starts loading the tableView of posts.

The code for loading an image in cell is

```
if let imageToFetch = post.objectForKey("postImage") as? PFObject {
self.postImageHeight.constant = 500
if let fetchImage = imageToFetch.objectForKey("image") as? PFFile{
    fetchImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let imageData = imageData {
                let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                self.postImage.image = image
                self.imageGesture(self.postImage)
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    //Make the size constarints of the image 0
    self.postImageHeight.constant = 0
}
```

But it seems like a unstable approach as I'm hardcoding the image height. Any help on the issue would be appriciated.

Comment: Do you actually want to _stretch/scale_ the image, for the purpose of consistent looking of cells?

Comment: I would like the imageview to be the same size proportionally to the image. So an image in landscape would be wider than it is taller and vice versa for portrait images. The image inside will always be set to aspect fit.

Comment: So your trouble is really how to read image pixel information from the data you got from server?

Comment: No, my general question is, I want to have a facebook like feed, where the user can post text and an image. The post should then expand to fit the user's post content. Text and image. The text expands ok. For any post with an image I currently set the height of the imageview to 500. I know there must be a better way

Comment: You could only adjust to the correct height/width after you got the real image.

Answer (score 0):

You can change them using the image's `size` property. But for this, you need to use a fixed width referenced here as `kImageWidth`

```
self.postImageHeight.constant = kImageWidth * image.size.height / image.size.width
self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: This is a good answer, Now, the image resizes correctly. But only when I scroll past the image and back up. The actual cell wont resize with layoutIfNeeded.

Comment: There use self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPath() between self.tableView.beginUpdates()  and self.tableView.endUpdates() using delegate to the viewController

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: calculate `postImageHeight` manually after setting `postImage.image`:

```
/// .....
self.postImage.image = image
self.postImageHeight.constant = self.postImage.bounds.size.width * image.size.height / image.size.width
/// .....
```

A better option is to add a special method to `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```
func setPostImageWithImage(image: UIImage?) {
    postImageView.image = image

    // Manually adjust image height.
    if let image = image {
        postImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = postImageView.bounds.size.width * image.size.height / image.size.width
    }
    else {
        // Collapse if there is no image.
        postImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, shinoys222 had this calculation and it works but the problem is, the image is fetched from the web. So, the cell image height is set after the cell has been loaded. I cannot seem to reload the cell without having weird effects from the table.

Comment: I was having the same problem and decided to wait until the image is load and then insert a new cell.

Comment: How did you insert the new cell after the image load?

Comment: How do **you** download posts? Starting activity indicator, call `findObjects...`, then stop the activity indicator? Don't stop it just after you got the objects, wait until related iamges are downloaded, then stop the spinner.

Comment: No I understand that, but the imageview should resize after it downloads. It currently doesnt. If I scroll down and back up the image height is correct

Comment: Do you use dynamic row height? `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: Yes, although I have tableView.estimatedrowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: No, you should specify an actual value for `estimatedRowHeight` and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for `rowHeight`. And reload a cell after setting `imageView` by calling `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(...)` method.

Comment: I have tried that using a delegate method and reloading the cell but it causes weird issues on scroll. Other cells without an image become the same size as the cell with an image